# Read ID of NFC Tag?not displayed

Tags: android, nfc

I followed [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-nfc-example-to-read-tag-info-of.html) tutorial to Read NFC tag

when I scan a NFC tag Its displays nothing,but when I scan a Empty NFC tag /new NFC tag is says Empty tag

How to fix this actually i want unique ID NFC tag only I also checked with [this](https://gist.github.com/luixal/5768921) code.

actually I need Only Unique ID of NFC like
below
[image]

can any one help me

Answer (score 2):

I have one way used below code for converting `byte[]` to `HexString`

```
public String convertByteArrayToHexString(byte[] data) {
    char[] hexArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    char[] hexChars = new char[data.length * 2];
    int v;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        v = data[i] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[i * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[i * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }

    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

You just need to pass your `TagId` as a `Argument` like

```
  @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   setIntent(intent);

   Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
   String nfcTagSerial = convertByteArrayToHexString(tag.getId());
   }
```

You will get result in `nfcTagSerial`  like

```
0450497A871F80
```

Comment: @Don'tBenegative You just add this code in `onResume(..)`  of `MainActivity` in your [Demo Example](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-nfc-example-to-read-tag-info-of.html)

Comment: @Don'tBenegative No men!!i don't have time. Already give you the code. Now i don't give you feed in your mouth. just used your brain.

Comment: sorry sir I am unable to get out put...

Comment: @Don'tBenegative How you tried? show me